# Search within activeRecord relation ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

This is my controller code

```
@users = User.all
```

Inside view I have a drop-down from which I select a user. I want to show details of that users before submitting. For that I need that users details. I don't want to go to database again. So how do I search in @users object for that user's details. Which one is faster and more efficient searching in already loaded object or sending a ajax request for that record ?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you do

```
def index
   @users = user.all
end
```

instance variables from your controller action are available in the view

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= @user.name %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to display also association, in your controller index action use

```
@users = User.includes(:your_association)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways.
1. We can write ajax call according to user and display data by ajax.
2. Make content in the same page and show or hide them according to user

Way 2 is least preferred way put the details in the same page and us js to display its content.
For eg. we have user with id=2 and you want to see all the details of this user then withing loop of user make details of all user and hide them

```
<div id='user-1' class='hidden'> all details of user 1</div>
<div id='user-2' class='hidden'> all details of user 2</div>
<div id='user-3' class='hidden'> all details of user 3</div>
```

Write a simple Jquery or JavaScript which will remove hidden class according to your selected user and user will be able to see details of those user which they want to see (don't forget to hide all other user information). It will increase the page size and we have lot of those data which we do not want to show.